# Python check if a directory exists, then create it if necessary and save graph to new directory?

Tags: python

so I want this to be independent of the computer the code is used on, so I want to be able to create a directory in the current directory and save my plots to that new file. I looked at some other questions and tried this (I have two attempts, one commented out):

```
    import os
    from os import path
    #trying to make shift_graphs directory if it does not already exist:

    if not os.path.exists('shift_graphs'):
        os.mkdirs('shift_graphs')

    plt.title('Shift by position on '+str(detector_num)+'-Detector')
    #saving figure to shift_graphs directory
    plt.savefig(os.path.join('shift_graphs','shift by position on '+str(detector_num)+'-detector'))
    print "plot 5 done"
    plt.clf
```

I get the error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mkdirs'
```

I also want to know if my idea of saving it in the directory will work, which I haven't been able to test because of the errors I've been getting in the above portion.

Comment: There's `os.mkdir`, and `os.makedirs`. There's no `os.mkdirs`. (As the error message already explained to you.)

Comment: okay got it, sorry I'm pretty new to programming

Comment: I use `if not os.path.exists(new_path):` \ `os.makedirs(new_path)`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`os.mkdirs()` is not a method in os module.
if you  are making only one direcory then use `os.mkdir()` and if there are multiple directories try using `os.makedirs()`
Check [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for either:

`os.mkdir`

Or `os.makedirs`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

os.makedirs makes all the directories, so if I type in shell (and get nothing):

```
$ ls
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir(os.getcwd())
[]
>>> os.makedirs('alex/is/making/a/path')
>>> os.listdir(os.getcwd())
['alex']
```

It has made all the directories and subdirectories. os.mkdir would throw me an error, because there is no "alex/is/making/a" directory.